# Combobox Binding source

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

Im have folowing wpf window:

```
     <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ports="clr-namespace:System.IO.Ports;assembly=System"
        Title="MainWindow"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="portNames"
                            MethodName="GetPortNames"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type ports:SerialPort}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <ComboBox Name="cbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource portNames}}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />

</Window>
```

I m using the ObjectDataProvider to populate the Com Port combobox.
But i dont know how to populate other comboboxes.
C# functions used :

```
 private void LoadBaudRates()
        {
            cboxBaudRate.DataContext = new int[] { 9600, 14400, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200, 128000 };
            cboxBaudRate.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        private void LoadParity()
        {
            cboxParity.DataContext = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Parity));
        }
        private void LoadFlowControl()
        {
            cboxFlowControl.DataContext = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Handshake));
        }
        private void LoadCOMPorts()
        {
            var comPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            //cboxCOMPorts.DataContext = comPorts;
            this.cboxCOMPorts.DataContext = comPorts;
        }
```

Comment: What other comboboxes?

Comment: @DaniDărăban, do you mean in XAML?

Comment: i have 4 comboboxes , i managed to populate Com Ports but the other 3 i dont know how to populate them, yes im xml code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate other `ComboBoxes` in XAML then for `Enum` you also create `ObjectDataProvider`, as you did with COM ports:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="HandshakeValues" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
   <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      <x:Type TypeName="ports:Handshake" />
   </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource HandshakeValues}}"/>
```

and for `int` array you can do something like this:

```
<ComboBox>
   <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
      <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
         <sys:Int32>9600</sys:Int32>
         <sys:Int32>14400</sys:Int32>
         <sys:Int32>19200</sys:Int32>
         <sys:Int32>38400</sys:Int32>
         <sys:Int32>57600</sys:Int32>
         <sys:Int32>115200</sys:Int32>
         <sys:Int32>128000</sys:Int32>
      </x:Array>
   </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

where `sys` is `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Comment: This is my rate combobox: <ComboBox Name="cboxBaudRate"
                              Width="85"
                              Height="23"
                              Margin="77,38,449,333"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                              TabIndex="1" /> I get some errors if i paste the item.source content